# One Sample or Two Sample Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, bias, sample

I have a large group of 40m with performance $P_i$ known for each month $i.$
Out of that group, I have a random sample of about 5k with performance $P_{1i}$ for each month $i.$

I want to be able compare the performance of the sample to overall performance of 40m users -
Should I use 1-sample test where the 'constant' is $P_i?$ is it statistically correct? is it legit to assume that the 40m is my constant and the number I want to compare to while ignoring its variability?
Taking a random sample from 40m for comparison is hard to achieve in my system

Note that the group sizes are extremely different and my sample is approximately $0.00012\%$ from the 40m group

Thanks

Comment: I think you may be using 'plus or minus' $\pm$ `$\pm$` where you mean 'approximately' $\approx$ `$\approx$`.

Comment: thanks. any suggestion regarded to my question :) ?

Comment: See Answer. (But it is not clear why you suppose a random sample of size 40,000 might give a substantially incorrect result.)

Comment: In what way is the monthly performance "known" in the large group?

Comment: We know its proportion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be about the difference
between (a) comparing a sample of 40,000,000 with a sample of 5,000 and (b) taking the large sample to be the population and comparing the small sample with the population success probability. You will get essentially the same result either way, but there are quibbles either way--neither of which makes much difference here.

- Comparing a large sample with a subset of it is deprecated. It's best to compare the subset with with the *remainder* of the large sample in order to have two independent samples (no overlapping elements).
- Assuming that the large sample is essentially the population may be misleading if the large sample differs from the population.

In terms of the procedure `prop.test` in R, suppose we have large sample `x` and small sample `y` as simulated in R below. Neither test rejects. [Because of the large sample sizes, continuity correction is not uses.]

```
set.seed(2020)
p = .3
x = rbinom(50*10^6, 1, p)
y = sample(x, 40000)
```

Test whether large and small samples have the same success probability.

```
prop.test(c(sum(x),sum(y)), c(length(x), length(y)), cor=F)

    2-sample test for equality of proportions 
    without continuity correction

data:  c(sum(x), sum(y)) out of c(length(x), length(y))
X-squared = 0.005256, df = 1, p-value = 0.9422
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.004326224  0.004658624
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.3001162 0.2999500
```

Test whether the success probability of the small sample is equal to the
population success probability (really $p_{pop} = 0.3$ but taken to be $p_{pop} = \hat p_{pop} = 0.3001162).$

```
p.pop = mean(x)
prop.test(sum(y), length(y), p.pop, cor=F)

        1-sample proportions test 
        without continuity correction

data:  sum(y) out of length(y), null probability p.pop
X-squared = 0.0052603, df = 1, p-value = 0.9422
alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.3001162
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2954788 0.3044597
sample estimates:
      p 
0.29995
```

*Addendum:* I am puzzled by two things in your Question: (1) You say that ne new sample is "is approximately 0.00012% from the 40m group." That would be about $48,$ not $4800\approx 5000$, So I assume you mean the fraction $0.00012 = 0.012\%.$ (2) You say "Taking a random sample from 40m for comparison is hard to achieve in my system." So I suppose the smaller sample
is a new sample from the population, which may or may not involve some of the same subjects as in the large sample.

If the sample of 40m is random (and unsorted), then using the
initial or the final $5000$ should be essentially the same as taking a random sample from among the $5000.$ Maybe this is
easier to do in your system.

Below is a test
between two samples of size $5000:$ one of them `w` freshly generated with
success probability $0.3$ and the other `v` taken as the first
$5000$ elements of `x` above. Again, there is no significant difference in the proportion of successes.

```
set.seed(2020)
p = .3;  x = rbinom(50*10^6, 1, p)   
v = x[1:5000]
set.seed(909)
p = .3;  w = rbinom(5000, 1, p)

prop.test(c(sum(v),sum(w)), c(5000,5000), cor=F)

    2-sample test for equality of proportions 
    without continuity correction

data:  c(sum(v), sum(w)) out of c(5000, 5000)
X-squared = 0.094279, df = 1, p-value = 0.7588
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.02067294  0.01507294
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
0.2934 0.2962
```

Comment: 1) Saying that the 40m is all my data and knowledge about the proportion for a month - isnt enough to conclude its my population proportion ? 2) Does the simulation prove that a small sample of lets say a random 5000 will provide approximately the same proportion of the population ? if so why should i take the random sample rather than the population i already have ?

Comment: With samples as large as 5000 you should not be surprised that proportions are about the same. So maybe there is no point looking at the smaller samples. And maybe looking at the smaller independent samples will occasionally alert you that on a particular day you can't trust the larger sample for some reason.

Comment: Thanks! so in case i have a 3 months data and i wish to group by month (so each group will have approximately 40m users) and each small sample with particular event is about 5k, you think i can perform a proportional Z-test for each month separately ? comparing each month sample to its "population assumed" proportion ?

Comment: I think that would work.